# How to check if current item of a loop is selected in a second loop of items?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, each

I have a jQuery loop which is checking the current item in the loop against another list of items— if there is a match, I need to clear the value from the current item in the loop.

```
$('.subDDL').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == ****second loop id's here**** ) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //Do something else.
    }
})
```

To try and explain a little differently, I have a table with an "include" check box. Then I have a sub table which can include an item from the main table but ONLY when that option from the main table is included.

So, when I loop over the sub table items I need to go to the main table and check the included options. If there are any sub values included which are *not* included in the main table, I need to set the value of the current sub item to "None", basically removing that value which is not allowed.

Comment: If you could please provide a fiddle, i could show you how it's done. The question is too abstract for anyone to learn from it.

Comment: Can you provide us HTML code of the table ?

Comment: Here is a fiddle to show the table http://jsfiddle.net/JVf8F/ so in the example, as "Main Table 1" is not selected above, when I loop over the sub table, the 3rd item needs the value setting back to "None".

Comment: Hi @Mike86 , I've added a fiddle in my above comment - Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: I've posted my answer, if you have any questions about it - feel free to post comment under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you correctly, this is what you need:

```
var checkboxes = $(".cbx");
var selects = $('.subDDL');

function sanitizeSelectMenus($el) {

  selects.each(function (i, v) {
    var $v = $(v);
    var current = $v.find(":selected");
    var forbidden = !! $el ? $el.parents("td").next() : checkboxes.filter(":not(:checked)").parents("td").next();
    $.each(forbidden, function (i, v) {
        if (current.text() == $(v).text()) {
            current.removeAttr("selected");
            $($v.children()[0]).attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
  });
}

checkboxes.on("click", function (e) {
  var $el = $(e.target);
  if ($el.is(":not(:checked)")) {
    sanitizeSelectMenus($el);
  }
});

selects.on("change", function () {
  sanitizeSelectMenus();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JVf8F/6/

You can also achieve the same by adding [data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to your checkboxes and to the selection fields, thus making search by text (which might be pretty inaccurate) redundant. I chose to show you the example above, because it seemed like your HTML is generated by something and i didn't know how much control you have over it.

Comment: Thank you @Mike86 you are correct, I am creating the table from a `for` loop which also has another sub loop to create the extra rows. Although the way I solved this problem was quite different to your answer, your answer is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help as the question is slightly unclear (to me).  Here's how you could do a nested loop to compare items:

```
for(var i = 0; i < table1.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < table2.length; j++) {
        if(table1Items[i].value == table2Items[j].value) {
            alert("Match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I used an array to check...
As I was looping over the rows in the main table (before I get to the sub table) I created an array and pushed each un-checked row into that array. All I needed to do in my `if` statement is `($.inArray(DsID[0], DsAry) >= 0)` which means that if the sub row value appears in the array, I need to remove it.

Thank you to everyone for their help.